# Populating a zenity list with results from mysql

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, zenity

I'm doing a small project using BASH for a "Phone Book". It stores the data in a mysql database and uses a temporary file to work with the Selects.

I'm using zenity visual interface, so I want to display the data stored in the database using the Zenity List Dialog. For doing that, I need to use the values of the columns individually, so I need to use the awk command to get those, but I'm having trouble in combining both zenity and awk commands.

Storing the values of the database, separated by \t in the temporary file.

```
echo "SELECT name,address,telephone,email FROM agenda" | mysql projAgenda -N -u root -p12345 >> tempAgenda.dat
```

Displaying the data using zenity --list

```
awk -F'\t' '{zenity --list --title="Listar registos" --text="" --column="Name" --column="Address" --column="Telephone" --column="E-mail" $1 $2 $3 $4}' tempAgenda.dat
```

But I'm always getting the same error:

> awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =

Can someone help? I know I might be screwing up really big in trying to mix those two commands, but can't think of doing it another way.

EDIT: Output of the query (separated by tabs):

```
José Manel  Rua António Cão 219886868   zemaneli@live.com 
Cláudio Pinto   Praça Dom Rui da Camara 219886820   claudiopinto@live.com
```

Comment: Isn't zenity a shell command?  Why are you trying to run it inside an awk script?

Comment: Can you not run the zenity command and pipe it to awk?

Comment: edit your question to include 1-2 lines output from the `mysql` query. Good luck.

Comment: I edited the post shelter. The awk is working well. I've tried

`awk -F'\t' '{ print "NAME: " $1 "\nADDRESS: " $2 "\nTELEPHONE:" $3 "\nE-MAIL: "$4 }' tempAgenda.dat`

And it works. I'm really new to this, only started learning bash properly yesterday so I thought  zenity would work like print, so I basically tried to replace it. I don't know how I can mix both commands, and I know it makes sense I can't put one inside another. What should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the tab delimiter returned by mysql with a new line since `zenity` expects each column to be on a separate line when it reads from stdin. You can use `tr` for that:

```
mysql -N ... | tr '\t' '\n' | zenity --list --title="Listar registos" --text="" --column="Name" --column="Address" --column="Telephone" --column="E-mail"
```

This would produce the following list:

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't do the job because the reason I'm displaying using the zenity list dialog is to show all of them in one window... but thanks anyway

Comment: I display all of them in one window. Have you tried it?

Comment: Wait the comment I made just got outdated. Let me check. It looks good.

Comment: Yeah, I added the second solution later. I also couldn't believe that you want to display every contact in it's own window :)

Comment: Yep! Problem solved! I didn't need to change the separator, since the values were separated by tabs I used `sed 's/\t/\n/g'` and it worked nicely

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I also figured that out :) .. I never knew that mysql will output tab separated data when output gets piped (or redirected to a file). Have also learned a lot in this post. Thanks too! ;)

Comment: /offtopic I love the combination of Spanish and German here. Makes me wanna sing "we are the world" :P